# Email greeting token not working with mosaico

Tags: civimail, tokens, mosaico

Building a mailing with mosaico

Contact email greeting not showing in final mail

(shows in html preview) mail sent as test and as mailing. No greeting in either.

d 7.66 c 5.10.3

other contact tokens (first name etc) are showing

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Craig, is it a custom token or the standard civicrm one? We had reports of custom tokens being lost due to the GDPR extension, which has now been fixed. Wondering if its that?

Comment: As far as I could tell it was the standard civi one. Will see if the GDPR exctension needs updating and give it a whirl- thanks for pointer Parvez!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Parvez, for pointing this out.

As well as Mosaico we had the GDPR extension installed. Upgrading to latest version GDPR has fixed the issue!